# How to buy with ethers js using Uniswap Universal router on Base? calling execute function

Tags: node.js, solidity, ethers.js, uniswap

I want to buy new tokens launched on base using Uniswap Universal router on Base with node js and ether js libraries. Im calling execute function but I'm having many problems.

Here is the code:

`
const {ethers} = require("ethers")

const AbiCoder = new ethers.utils.AbiCoder()

```
// const tokenToBuy = '0xe67aB9Efb46d987d2aF816597F6716069A8a7426' //KIF

//Router
const routerAddress = '0x198EF79F1F515F02dFE9e3115eD9fC07183f02fC' // router
const file = fs.readFileSync("./B_Base/ABIUniversal.json", 'utf8') // Calls sushi ABI
const routerAbi = JSON.parse(file)
const routerContract = new ethers.Contract(routerAddress, routerAbi, signer)

// token input
const prompt = ps()
const tokenToBuy = String(prompt("Enter token name: ")) 

//wbnb to spend
const spend = ethers.utils.parseEther("0.0001")

const commands = 0x00

const path = [AbiCoder.encode(WETH), AbiCoder.encode(5000), AbiCoder.encode(tokenToBuy)]

 // Encode the parameters
const inputs = AbiCoder.encode(WALLET_ADDRESS, spend, 0, path, false)

const buy = async () => { // .execute execute(bytes commands,bytes[] inputs,uint256 deadline)
    const buy = await routerContract.execute(
      commands,
      inputs,
      Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 10)
      
    receipt = await buy.wait()
    transactionHash = receipt.transactionHash
    console.log(transactionHash)
    
}


buy()`
```

There is an error when encoding the path and input to call the execute function. I don't understand the error is showing me I have been following ethers documentation and Uniswap docs too.

Error:

`    if (types.length !== values.length) {
^

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
    at AbiCoder.encode (/home/oriok/DEV/degen/Arbitrum/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/lib/abi-coder.js:82:37)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/oriok/DEV/degen/Arbitrum/B_Base/testinUni.js:52:24)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47`
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there any other router that allows you to buy any kind of token? I have been using SwapRouterV2 but doesnt allow me to buy some tokens. There aren't much solutions on Uniswap community discord either.

Comment: Provide examples of what specific library versions you are using to interact with Uniswap to help others, as well show examples of how you are making the call. Verify in the library which parameter is having `length()` run on it, as the error is saying that you cannot get the length of something that is undefined.

Comment: Im using 5.7.0 ether.js library, but why it is the error pointing at the library? There must be somthing wrong in the code. I'm calling it like this:

`const {ethers} = require("ethers")

const AbiCoder = new ethers.utils.AbiCoder()`

Answer (score 0):

Asked for version as there is a lot of overhaul from v5 to v6 of etherjs: refer to [5.7/packages/abi/lib/abi-coder.js](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/blob/v5.7/packages/abi/lib/abi-coder.js#L80C5-L93C7) for the changes.

It appears that the structure you're passing to `encode` when you're creating the `path` variable is where this is hitting because you should have a defined pair of `types` and `values` passed to the `encode()` function.

So where you pass the following:

```js
const path = [AbiCoder.encode(WETH), AbiCoder.encode(5000), AbiCoder.encode(tokenToBuy)
```

Based on abi-coder.js(v5.7) it's looking that types and values match in pairs:

```js
AbiCoder.prototype.encode = function (types, values) {
        var _this = this;
        if (types.length !== values.length) {
            logger.throwError("types/values length mismatch", logger_1.Logger.errors.INVALID_ARGUMENT, {
                count: { types: types.length, values: values.length },
                value: { types: types, values: values }
            });
        }
```

This *should* look a little more like:

```js
const path = [
    AbiCoder.encode(["string"], [WETH]),
    AbiCoder.encode(["uint"], [5000]),
    AbiCoder.encode(["string"], [tokenToBuy])
]
```

So if you're only defining values and not predefining types for each value you would see that the amount of values (length) would not match the number of types in length either. Not providing the pair means that one would in fact be undefined.

However I would also revisit the reuse of encode on the following line - unsure how the ABI structure works with nested encoding.

I don't have intimate familiarity with etherjs, and am referring to structures available on the [ethers AbiCoder documentation](https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/utils/abi/coder/).

Comment: I understand, this is helpful thank you signus Im not an experienced dev I'm very lost on this.
So encode for the second param of the execute() function should be like this
`const inputs = AbiCoder.encode(["string", "uint", "uint", "bytes", "bool"], [WALLET_ADDRESS, spend, 0, path, false])`

Got this error poping up rn:

`Arbitrum/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib/index.js:247
        throw this.makeError(message, code, params);
        ^

Error: invalid arrayify value (argument="value", value=["0x0`

Comment: @0xDegen - I would implore you to further explore the library as StackOverflow is not the best place to try and iterate over every single issue you face. I would suggest focusing on how to understand what parameters (including their types) are necessary for what you are trying to accomplish. Additionally, I would offer a suggestion that if you are not already anything you are doing you try to accomplish in a testnet so as to reduce risk while you are learning how to use these tools. Should you have additional modifications to your question I can surely help to expand upon my original answer.